# How to make loading animation in android xml

Tags: android, xml, android-animation

I would like to create an Animation with 3 dots (one Is bigger than the other two and have different color), this animation should loop at start center one should be bigger after that dot on the right should be bigger and change color.
I created this XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <aapt:attr name="android:drawable">
        <vector
            android:width="300dp"
            android:height="80dp"
            android:viewportWidth="300"
            android:viewportHeight="80">
            <path
                android:name="left_selected"
                android:pathData="M30,44m-30,0a30,30 0,1 1,60 0a30,30 0,1 1,-60 0"
                android:fillColor="#CBA818"/>
     
            <path
                android:name="center"
                android:pathData="M150,40m-40,-0a40,40 0,1 0,80 -0a40,40 0,1 0,-80 -0"
                android:fillColor="#757575"/>
            <path
                android:name="right"
                android:pathData="M270,44m-30,-0a30,30 0,1 0,60 -0a30,30 0,1 0,-60 -0"
                android:fillColor="#757575"/>
        </vector>

    </aapt:attr>
    <target android:name="path">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:duration="217"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
                    android:propertyName="pathData"
                    android:repeatCount="infinite"
                    android:repeatMode="reverse"
                    android:valueFrom="..."
                    android:valueTo=..."
                    android:valueType="pathType" />
                <objectAnimator
                    android:duration="144"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
                    android:propertyName="pathData"
                    android:repeatCount="infinite"
                    android:repeatMode="reverse"
                    android:startOffset="217"
                    android:valueFrom="..."
                    android:valueTo="..."
                    android:valueType="pathType" />
                <objectAnimator
                    android:duration="239"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
                    android:propertyName="pathData"
                    android:repeatCount="infinite"
                    android:repeatMode="reverse"
                    android:startOffset="361"
                    android:valueFrom="..."
                    android:valueTo="..."
                    android:valueType="pathType" />
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
</animated-vector>
```

How could I change a color of dot in animation tag? Is my way of thinking correct with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach

XML:-

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/clCenterArrows"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ivImage"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/ivImage"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/ivImage"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivImage">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivArrows"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_tag_instruction_arrows"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/vTagCenter"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/d12"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/d12"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_fill_red"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ivArrows"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/ivArrows"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/ivArrows"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivArrows" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/vAnim1"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/d12"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/d12"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_fill_red"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ivArrows"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/ivArrows"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/ivArrows"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivArrows" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/vAnim2"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/d12"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/d12"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_fill_red"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ivArrows"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/ivArrows"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/ivArrows"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivArrows" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Kotlin:-

```
 val runnableAnim = object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                vAnim1?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                vAnim2?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                vAnim1
                    ?.animate()
                    ?.scaleX(3f)
                    ?.scaleY(3f)
                    ?.alpha(0f)
                    ?.setDuration(1000)
                    ?.withEndAction {
                        kotlin.run {
                            vAnim1?.scaleX = 1f
                            vAnim1?.scaleY = 1f
                            vAnim1?.alpha = 1f
                        }
                    }

                vAnim2
                    ?.animate()
                    ?.scaleX(3f)
                    ?.scaleY(3f)
                    ?.alpha(0f)
                    ?.setDuration(700)
                    ?.withEndAction {
                        kotlin.run {
                            vAnim2?.scaleX = 1f
                            vAnim2?.scaleY = 1f
                            vAnim2?.alpha = 1f
                        }
                    }

                animationHandler.postDelayed(this, 1500)
            }
        }

        runnableAnim.run()
```

[This is the output of the animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLZeR.jpg)